# got "E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic Release' does not have a Release file." while installing nodejs on new kde neon

Tags: linux, software-installation, kde, libraries, kde-neon

I run this commands

```
sudo apt-get install curl software-properties-common
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
```

on kde neon, and errors

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 14.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                             
Hit:2 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://by.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                      
Hit:5 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                   
Ign:7 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bionic InRelease                      
Ign:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic InRelease                                    
Get:9 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user bionic InRelease [153 kB]                       
Err:10 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bionic Release                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.112.204 80]
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                          
Ign:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic-updates InRelease                           
Err:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic Release                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.112.204 80]
Err:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic-updates Release                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.112.204 80]
Hit:15 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:6 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done                                                          
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bionic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Comment: Output of `lsb_release -a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a file in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` contains Debian package sources
mixed with Ubuntu release names. Those repositories don't exist. Make sure you only add package sources destined for your Ubuntu release.

Run

```
grep -rl 'debian\.org/debian' /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

to find the file containing those entries.

Edit the corresponding file and remove all entries containing `http://deb.debian.org/debian` or `http://security.debian.org/debian-security`
(e.g. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`) or delete the file if it's a single file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` containing only such entries.

Then run

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -
```

again followed by

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

to install `nodejs`.